# Why array registers only the last object multiple times Nodejs

Tags: node.js, arrays, object, azure-table-storage

Im trying to fill an array with n objects but it just register the last object n times this is my code :

```
async function show(carId,debut,fin){
    let score = {}
    let array = [];
    res = await ScoreData(carId);
    for(i = 0; i < res.entries.length ; i++){
        
        date = res.entries[i].Timestamp._.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
        if (date >= debut && date <= fin){
            score.roadSpeed_1 = (res.entries[i].speed_1._)/((res.entries[i].speed_1._)+ (res.entries[i].speed_2._) + (res.entries[i].speed_3._))*10000;
            score.roadSpeed_2 = (res.entries[i].speed_2._)/((res.entries[i].speed_1._)+ (res.entries[i].speed_2._) + (res.entries[i].speed_3._))*10000;
            score.roadSpeed_3 = (res.entries[i].speed_3._)/((res.entries[i].speed_1._)+ (res.entries[i].speed_2._) + (res.entries[i].speed_3._))*10000;
            score.Acceleration = Math.round(res.entries[i].millage._ / res.entries[i].Vehicle_speed._)
            console.log(res.entries[i].millage._ / res.entries[i].Vehicle_speed._)
            array.push(score);
        }
    }
    console.log(array)   
}
```

This is the result :

```
[
  { roadSpeed_1: 100, roadSpeed_2: 0, roadSpeed_3: 0, Acceleration: 4 },
  { roadSpeed_1: 100, roadSpeed_2: 0, roadSpeed_3: 0, Acceleration: 4 },
  { roadSpeed_1: 100, roadSpeed_2: 0, roadSpeed_3: 0, Acceleration: 4 },
  { roadSpeed_1: 100, roadSpeed_2: 0, roadSpeed_3: 0, Acceleration: 4 },
  { roadSpeed_1: 100, roadSpeed_2: 0, roadSpeed_3: 0, Acceleration: 4 },
  { roadSpeed_1: 100, roadSpeed_2: 0, roadSpeed_3: 0, Acceleration: 4 },
  { roadSpeed_1: 100, roadSpeed_2: 0, roadSpeed_3: 0, Acceleration: 4 },
  { roadSpeed_1: 100, roadSpeed_2: 0, roadSpeed_3: 0, Acceleration: 4 },
  { roadSpeed_1: 100, roadSpeed_2: 0, roadSpeed_3: 0, Acceleration: 4 }
]
```

Comment: What is the value of `res.entries.length`?

Comment: res.entries.length is how many objects azrue returned, so i use it to loop through all the objects until i reach the last object which is (res.entries.length)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects in JavaScript are passed by reference. When more than one variable is set to store either an object , array or function , those variables will point to the same allocated space in the memory. Passed by reference. Source : [Link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-get-a-grip-on-reference-vs-value-in-javascript-cba3f86da223/)

Better solution i guess :

```
array.push({roadspeed_1: operation 1, roadspeed_2: operation 2 ,roadspeed_3: operation 3 });
```